# How to call a function inside a Template literal in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, template-literals

I am using node js , express. I am trying to call a function in template literal.
I made a module and import in main file and then add the function to app.locals and accessing in my views that works fine. But when i try to use it in template literals and also in my public file it give me error "**currencyToWords is not defined**".

> I think in public file it makes sense because i make public folder static.
> but in  my views it is weird because when i use it in html it works but when i use it in template literal it gives error.

I want to use the currencyToWords function in template literals to change the response.

**I have one solution** that i can make the file in public folder and add the function in script in that file and import in footer but i dont want to do that.

Can anybody help me in solving the issue.

**My app stucture**
[image: app stucture]
module.exports = { currencyConverter }

**In app.js**
app.js is my main file where i create server

```
var { currencyToWords } = require('./config/functions');
app.locals.currencyToWords = currencyToWords;
```

by adding in locals i can access it in my application any where

**This code is working:**

```
 <div class="fix pull_right">
  <h3><%= currencyToWords(property.propertyDetails.price)%></h3>
 </div>
```

**This is not working**

```
var a =`
  <p>${currencyToWords(property.propertyDetails.price)}</p>
`;
```

the above code is same but only difference is first one is use in ejs tags and second in ejs and template literals.

**Here is the documentation from express about app.locals**
app.locals
The app.locals object has properties that are local variables within the application.

```
console.dir(app.locals.title)
// => 'My App'

console.dir(app.locals.email)
// => 'me@myapp.com'
```

Once set, the value of app.locals properties persist throughout the life of the application, in contrast with res.locals properties that are valid only for the lifetime of the request.

You can access local variables in templates rendered within the application. **This is useful for providing helper functions to templates**, as well as application-level data. Local variables are available in middleware via req.app.locals (see req.app)

```
app.locals.title = 'My App'
app.locals.strftime = require('strftime')
app.locals.email = 'me@myapp.com'
```

Comment: I take it you are sending the `currencyToWords` function from the server to the view? Or is it just a regular client-side JS function?

Comment: I tried sending currencyToWords function from server to view when rendering view and I also import it from a seperate util.js file but both methods show this error